# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting Remove Formula

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to remove conditional formatting on a cell only if it has a certain formula?

Right now I have

```
Cells(r, 4).Select      
With Selection
.FormatConditions.Item(1).Delete
End With
```

But I only want it to delete the formatting if the formula

```
="=ISBLANK(A19)=TRUE"
```

Does anyone know if that is a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    ClearFormulaCF Range("A1:A5"), "=ISBLANK(A19)=TRUE"

End Sub

'Remove any CF rule from cells in rng where the CF formula
'   matches the one provided
Sub ClearFormulaCF(rng As Range, sFormula As String)
    Dim rngCF As Range, c As Range, fc As FormatCondition

    On Error Resume Next
    'any cells with CF?
    Set rngCF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngCF Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no CF found

    For Each c In rngCF.Cells
        For Each fc In c.FormatConditions
            If fc.Formula1 = sFormula Then
                fc.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next fc
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Tim, sorry for not responding earlier, I was busy with other things. Can I ask a question? What is the order of operations here? If I land on a cell, do I call Sub Tester and Then Sub ClearFormulaCF? Or has Tester been called before?

Comment: "Tester" is just a stand-in for your actual code, to demonstrate how you would use  `ClearFormulaCF`